# Parameter optimization in a Gaussian linear state space model

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, kalman-filter

I'm working on reducing the runtime of an SSM, so I'm trying to replace as much of the generic implementation with analytic solutions.
Mine is a special case, where the observation model only consists of a linear combination of features, the transition matrix is identity, and all distributions are Gaussian.

My hope is that in this special case, the model parameters can be optimized analytically, similarly in spirit to the linear least squares problem.

My observation model is:
$$y_t = Fx_t + v, \quad \text{with} \quad v \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_v^2),$$
where $y_t$ is a scalar observed variable, $x_t$ is a vector of latent space variables, and $\sigma_v^2$ is a scalar observation variance and is not time-dependent. $\sigma_v$ is a model parameter.

$$F = \theta^T,$$
where $\theta$ is a vector of coefficients, defining a linear combination of my features. E.g. $x_t$ could be $(1,t,t^2)$, if I'm fitting a parabola. Then, $Fx_t$ would be $a+bt+ct^2$. $\theta$ is not time-dependent. These coefficients are the primary model parameters.

My transition model is:
$$x_t = Ax_{t-1} + w, \quad \text{with} \quad v \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_w^2),$$
where the transition matrix $A = I$. $\sigma_w^2$ are just constants.

My hope was to follow a similar procedure as for deriving the linear least squares equations from the log-likelihood optimization problem. But, unlike the least squares case, the variance of the ssm likelihood picks up a dependence on $\theta$.
$$L = \prod_t \mathcal{N}(y_t;F\mu_{t|t-1},F\Sigma_{t|t-1}F^T+\sigma_v^2).$$
Thus, when the gradient of the log-likelihood is taken with respect to $\theta$, the resulting equations are not linear.

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the literature on SSM. I'm hoping I can get closer to an analytic solution than evaluating $\log L$ many times and using a numerical optimization algorithm to find optimal $\theta$ and $\sigma_v$.

Does $\nabla_\theta\log L$ have a reasonably decent form to make Newton–Raphson faster than a non-derivative-aware algorithm?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what SSM stands for? It looks like estimate problem similar to the one solved by a Kalman filter. If so, then you could look at recursive least squares or solve for the stationary Kalman filter gain.

Comment: SSM stands for "state space model", as mentioned in the title. It is a Kalman filter. I tagged the question as such. I'll try searching for "recursive least squares". Thank you for the suggestion. Could you elaborate on solving for the stationary Kalman filter gain?

Comment: It might be that your SSM is not [observable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observability). You mentioned that $A=I$, in which case your system would only be observable if $F$ is full rank. However you also mentioned that it could be that $x_t=(1,t,t^2)$ but that can't be true if $A=I$, and that would also imply that $\sigma_w^2=0$